# How to refer to an array?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I forgot how to do this since it been a while, can someone please help me out. I am trying to refer to an array but I can remember the way is is suppose to be done. Please help.

```
CGPoint point [] = {    
    CGPointMake(10,10),
    CGPointMake(20,20),    
};

self.center = point;
```

Comment: A center can only be one point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need an array of points, at least not in this case. A center can only be one point:

```
self.center = CGPointMake(10,10);
```

The first integer is the x coordinate and the second is the y.

**Update:**

If I understand your question in the comments, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ?; i++) {
    [items objectAtIndex:i].center = CGPointMake(10*i,10*i);
}
```

Comment: How do I increase 10,10 each time because I have items being placed at 10,10  and I want to change it bit by bit for each item.

Comment: @mfvomo: Please don't ask new questions in comments. [Post a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) describing your full problem and what you've tried to solve it, and why that didn't work. Interactive programming help is not what comments on this site are for.